# How to use the 'File' type inputs in QGIS modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I would like to add a field to all shp-files in a directory and calculate the area. I tried with the parameter "File" but didn't find a way to conncet this input to the other algorithm/operators.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I too have always wondered how to use the "File" parameter. Instead, remove the directory field and use the **Vector layer** as your input ("*shp-File*"):

[image: Modeler]

Save the model with your parameters for your *field calculator*. Then go back to the *Processing Toolbox* menu and **right-click** your model. There should be a **"Execute as batch process"** option:

[image: Execute as batch process]

From the interface, click the button with the ellipsis ("...") and then **Select from filesystem**:

[image: Batch process menu]

Find the directory and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking all the .shp files. This will automatically populate each row in the batch menu. Then hit **Run**.

(*Hint: if you have a lot of shapefiles in your directory, instead of holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking through them all, sort it by **"Type"** which will group all the .shp files together. Then select the first .shp file, hold **Shift** and select the last .shp in the list.*)

Hope this helps!